# Magento: Ordering catalog/category model getResource

Tags: magento

I've got code that will get the child categories of a category.

```
$parent = $category_model->load($current_category->parent_id);
$_categories = explode(',',$parent->getChildren());
```

But it doesn't seem to keep the order that the sub-categories are placed in in the management interface.

I tried to use `->setOrder('position', 'ASC')` but it seems to not have access to that method.

Anyone know how to set the order of the above code?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I've got a list of category ids that are children of the parent I pass it. I want to get them in the order they are sorted in on the Category management page.

Comment: I mean, for what purpose are the IDs being used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do this a different way. Before, I was getting an array of category IDs, looping through them and loading a category each time. This meant I couldn't order them like a normal collection. So instead I've just thrown all the IDs into a collection to get all at once and in order.

```
$category_model = Mage::getModel('catalog/category');
$current_category = Mage::registry('current_category');
$parent = $category_model->load($current_category->parent_id);
$_categoriesArray = explode(',',$parent->getChildren());

$_categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array('in' => $_categoriesArray))
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->setOrder('position', 'ASC');
```